# why ionic www folder is showing blank content

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm new to ionic framework  and I want to deploy my app to my website and I put 'www' folder into my website but it only shows blank page .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running below command in the root directory,

```
ionic build
```

It will compile the project and create `www` folder for you.

Comment: I did this and I uplaoded www folder in my cpanel but it show empty page

Comment: when you run ionic serve in your project, does it show anything?

Comment: yes it shows in my localhost but when I upload www folder in my host it didn't show anythings

Comment: See the network log, it can not find any of the files, it gives 404 for each file

Comment: what should I do for resolving this?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but let's try, the www folder you uploaded was generated by ionic serve or ionic build?

Comment: I found the issue, instead of requesting to http://smart-lemon.ir/Ionic/www/main.js it is requesting http://smart-lemon.ir/main.js

Comment: Try adding this in your index.html of src folder, <base href = "/Ionic/www" /> and build again using ionic build

Comment: I did this and my website changed but still something is not loading

Comment: Images are not getting loaded

Comment: I am not expert on hosting, but if you change the image paths from /assets/shapes.svg to asses/shapes.svg, it works